# inequality and == in a if

Tags: c++, compare, inequality

Hello I want to understand how compiler read this code with inequality at first and after that check value like this example

```
int a, b, c;
    a = 4; b = 3; c = 5;
    if (a > b == c)
    {
        cout << "Hello";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "bye";
    }
```

Comment: What you are looking for is [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: `a > b == c` is equivalent to `(a > b) == c`, thanks to rules of operator precedence and associativity in C++.    It compares the result of `a > b`  for equality with `c`.   Since `a > b` when comparing `int`s gives a `bool` in C++ (which can only be equal numerically with either `0` or `1`) the code here will only ever print `"bye"`.

Answer (score 0):

As the OP points out, using two operators in a row is ambiguous syntax. Languages resolve this using a table of *operator precedence*, to decide which operator is evaluated first. The table for C++ is found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).